# joining mySQL tables with some rows being different

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 different tables in a mySQL database that are structured like this:

```
table_cart:

cart_id | item_id | quantity
----------------------------
00001     285       1
00002     482       2
00003     683       6
00004     627       1

table_products:

product_id  |  product_name    |   quantity
-------------------------------------------
285            some name           50
482            another name        40
683            one more name       35
627            yet another name    80
```

What I am trying to display is 2 things from table_cart (the item_id and the quantity) and 1 thing from table_products (the name). The problem is, when it grabs the quantity with my code, it chooses the one from table_products, which is not the one I need. I imagine I did something wrong with the joining of the tables but I tried INNER, LEFT, RIGHT, etc. and none is working.

My query is like this:

```
$product_rows = $this->query("
SELECT * FROM table_cart INNER JOIN table_products 
ON table_cart.item_id=table_products.product_id 
WHERE cart_id='".$cart_id."'"
");
```

And I then output it like:

```
$item_details = mysql_fetch_array($product_rows);

$item_details['item_id']
$item_details['name']
$item_details['quantity']
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `join` is fine.  The problem is the `select *` and the fact that two columns have the same name (`quantity` is in both tables).

You should list the columns you want explicitly:

```
SELECT c.item_id, p.name, p.quantity
FROM table_cart c INNER JOIN
     table_products p
     ON c.item_id = p.product_id 
WHERE cart_id='".$cart_id."'";
```